# Call a function from JavaScript on clicking Reload button in a window before unload function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function in JavaScript which executes when the close or refresh button is clicked.

```
$(window).bind("beforeunload",function(event) {
            return "Save or Not";
    }
});
```

This will give me a pop up which has 2 buttons when I click on the refresh button (Reload and Don't reload in Chrome). Now I want to call a function to redirect to my homepage if I click on the reload button. How can I do that?

Comment: `document.location.href = url;` but you are not supposed to prevent actions done by the user

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
  $(document).ready(function() {


      setTimeout(function() {

      var __redirect_to = 'url_where_to_send';//

      var _tags = ['button', 'input', 'a'], _els, _i, _i2;

      for(_i in _tags) {

          _els = document.getElementsByTagName(_tags[_i]);

          for(_i2 in _els) {

              if((_tags[_i] == 'input' && _els[_i2].type != 'button' && _els[_i2].type != 'submit' && _els[_i2].type != 'image') || _els[_i2].target == '_blank') continue;

              _els[_i2].onclick = function() {window.onbeforeunload = function(){};}

          }

     }

      window.onbeforeunload = function() {

          setTimeout(function() {

              window.onbeforeunload = function() {};

              setTimeout(function() {

                  document.location.href = __redirect_to;

              }, 500);

          },5);

          return 'Are you sure you want to leave this page?\n\nWait...Before you go:\n\n***************************************\n\n GET A FREE BOTTLE OF NeuroNZT\n\n***************************************\n\nTo receive your bottle FOR FREE - Click Cancel or Stay on Page below';

      }

      }, 500);

  });

  </script>
```